# Graph Neural Networks for fixed graphs

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I understand that the different graph neural network approaches (convolutional, attentional, message passing) excel at predicting the properties of graphs when the structure and features vary for each training instance. (example: predicting chemical properties of molecules)

How is the problem approached when the graph is fixed? Are there stronger modeling approaches for this special case of the general problem?
(example: predicting biological properties: one fixed network of genes and a training set of multiple instances of this network with different node-level features)